# Camera calibration and perspective correction in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I used calibration to get the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, and I dont know how to use this information in my perspective correction code. 
What OpenCV functions should I use?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your perspective correction code?  You will probably end up using [warpPerspective](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-warpperspective) in the end...

Comment: I have 2 blocks: calibration and perspective correction. 
Both codes are working fine, I want to put them on just one code.
I want to have the most accurate image from the perspective correction, that is why I would like to fix the camera parameters before I use WarpPerspective. But I dont know how to use this parameters that I already found.

Comment: You will have to post more specific details for anyone to be able to help you.